# In-app purchase custom price

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I've been searching for a while, but it may be too obvious and people don't post about it.
I want to know if I can put a dynamic price for a product.
I have a delivery application and the price may vary with the distance.
Also, it can be a non integer price, like $2,43.

Is it possible?
Also, I couldn't set a price at iTunes Connect, I need to be reviewed first?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about the price of your app? Based on which distance, from where to where?

Comment: No, actually, in-app purchase inside the app. The distances will be dynamic, it vary within position.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure. As singingAtom just answered unfortunately you need to choose one of the tiers available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by other poster, you cannot have variable in-app purchases. You have to select one of the provided price tiers.

Now assuming you are making a taxi-service app then what you need to do in your app is provide the user with a list of prices that are fetched from your server for example how much will it cost to go from point A to point B. You can then "charge" them outside of the in-app purchases using your own pricing service (credit card over the phone etc).

Again in-app purchase doesn't work with what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it's more or less what I need to do, I'll research some other solution then, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set custom prices for an In-app purchase. You need to set the price using one of the tiers available.

You can set different prices for the same product by editing the the In-app purchase, selecting a tier, setting a "Price Effective Date" and "Price End Date" and hitting the button "Add to schedule".

Comment: Thanks, that explains why nobody talk about that. Price tiers just shows up after being reviewed?

Comment: No, you can set a price tier before your app is reviewed.

Comment: this doesn't answer OPs question. He wants a variable price depending upon distance. You cannot change prices on the fly for each user

Comment: You can have a variable price - limited to the tiers available - by registering all the prices you might want and selecting the suitable one for the given distance.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This can now be done using [**Apple Pay**](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/)

You cannot set your own custom price for an in-app purchase, you can only use the ones that apple provides you with (this is most likely to stop things like in-app purchases for `$0.01` or `$100,000`). Apple gives you plenty of price ranges, so you could just use `$1.99` or `$2.99` for your needs. In-app purchases are mostly non-integer prices.

Yet, if you were to go threw a third-party, other than apple, say `PayPal` you could do this easily, yet you won't get as many functionalities that `IAPs` have, and it would be near impossible to trigger something like removing ads inside of the application on this payment unless you have a server that you are using for your application. To implement `PayPal`, you could look at their tutorial ***[HERE](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-iOS/)***.

In short, no, you cannot set your own prices for in-app purchases, you can only use the ones that Apple provides (which can range from `0.99` to `999.99`), yet, you can use a third-party like `PayPal` to get this functionality, although it really isn't needed