# How to set up a single In-App Purchase Product having multiple Price Tiers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, in-app

I have implemented In-App Purchases in various apps before wherein we can set a price based on a specific Tier for a Product.

Now in this case, **the price of the product depends on the number of people**. For example, a video will Cost **$ 0.99 for >20 students**, **for >50 students it will be $1.99** ,etc.

So, I thought of making different products for each such case.

Eg:

- Product1. VideoForUpto20Students for $0.99. (Video course 1)
- Product2. VideoForUpto50Students for $1.99. (Video course 1)

  So if I implement it in this way then if the number of students increase, then I will have to create more product Identifiers for a same Product.

Again, I have a number of Video Courses approx. 40 ! That means, the total number of product identifiers for **40 Video Courses** having **4 different prices**  will **(40 * 4) = 160 product identifiers.**

So, **do I need to create different product identifiers for the same product to set multiple prices** or is there any other alternative ?

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need different identifiers, after all you will be able to look at individual sales data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create different identifiers for every In-App Purchase unfortunately.

From the accepted answer here [In-app purchase custom price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386848/in-app-purchase-custom-price):

> As noted by other poster, you cannot have variable in-app purchases.
>   You have to select one of the provided price tiers.

While you aren't exactly making it so the price is changing a lot (since your idea isn't a delivery service), if it is going to change at all you are going to need to create multiple identifiers.

Comment: Hey, I have another question - that is if I make 4 IAP identifiers for single product, is there a possibility of my App getting rejected ?

Comment: Probably not. To be safe you should give them different names to differentiate between the various requirements/needs to buy them.

Comment: @JenJose just wondering was your app accepted? did you face any problems? I am asking because i am in the process of doing the same. Thanks

Comment: @MohamedAli we dropped that idea entirely. That app was closed so not sure about App Store rejections. The only issue we felt is creating and maintaining so many IAP ids.